# Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `div` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start componen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Currently trying to build a react native screen that displays a chessboard. I am using the react-chessboard component from https://github.com/Clariity/react-chessboard. My code is very basic and I just want to display the screen on an IOS phone using expo. Running this app in a web browser works and the chessboard displays. However, if I want to use a mobile device, I keep getting the error:

> Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `div`
> must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start
> component names with a capital letter.

Why is this happening?

```
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Chessboard} from 'react-chessboard';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <view>
      <Chessboard/>
    </view>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

React Native doesn't have `div`s, it has Views instead. React libraries will usually not translate into React Native libraries because the building blocks are not the same. You will most likely have to find a React Native library for your chessboard or build your own.